# LeafletJS best approach to object oriented

Tags: javascript, oop, leaflet, dom-events

I'm working a little project with leaflet js, and I want to know what is the best way best to make it OOP. Ok, here's the deal:

Create a 'class' that works with markers, these come from the DB. So, I think I'll create an array of objects, **am I right**?

My first question is, do I have to create a custom class, with the marker object as a property of this class, or extend the L.marker class from leaflet?

Second question: How to bind the click event on each of the markers, so this event can call and ajax request and bind a popup with the info.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([25.55246, -103.50328], 18);
    var marcas = [];

   L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/kinopio.kikc39gj/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    function Marcador(marca, usuario, seccional, identificador){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.identificador = identificador;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.seccional = seccional;
    }

    Marcador.prototype.verUsuario = function(){
        console.log(this.usuario);
    }

    Marcador.prototype.verVotos = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/votos/' + this.identificador,
            datatype: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                msg = $.parseJSON(data);
                //marcador.bindPopup('Votos: ' + msg[0].Votos ).openPopup();
                console.log(msg[0].Votos);
            }
        });

    }

    function onMapClick(e) {
//When clicking in the map, create a marker so i can register a new one to the DB...

        var formulario =    "<form action='/registro' id='registro' method='post'> " +
                                "<input name='usuario' placeholder='usuario'> " +
                                "<input name='password' placeholder='passwword'>" +
                                "<input name='seccional' placeholder='seccional'>" +
                                "<input name='latitud' type='hidden' value = " + e.latlng.lat  + ">" +
                                "<input name='longitud' type='hidden' value = " + e.latlng.lng + ">" +
                                "<input type='submit' value='Aceptar'>" +
                            "</form>"

        var marker = L.marker( e.latlng ).addTo( map ).bindPopup( formulario );

            marker.on("popupopen", function(){
               
                var forma = $('#registro');
                forma.on('submit', function(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: forma.attr('method'),
                        url: forma.attr('action'),
                        data: forma.serialize(),
                        success:function(data){
                            marker.closePopup();
                            marker.bindPopup( 'Usuario registrado exitosament' ).openPopup();
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        }

        function cargarRegistros(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/registrados',
                datatype: 'json',

                success: function(d){

                    $.each(d.marcadores, function(i, item){                        
                        marca = new L.marker( [ parseFloat(item.latitud), parseFloat( item.longitud) ] )
                                    .addTo(map).bindPopup();
                        marcas.push( new Marcador( marca, item.usuario, item.seccional, item.identificador ) );

                    });
                }
            });

            return marcas;
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);

        function clickMarcador(e){
            console.log(e.target  + '---' + e.currentTarget);
            if (e.target.id !== e.currentTarget) {
                console.log('hola');
            }
            
            e.stopPropagation();
    }

    $('#registrados').on('click', cargarRegistros);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just extend the `L.Marker` class to include the needed functionality, for instance, the click event, you could hook it when the `onAdd` method of the marker gets fired, and unhook it on the `onRemove` method: Here's an example in code (using $.getJSON from jQuery):

```
L.CustomMarker = L.Marker.extend({

  onAdd: function (map) {
    this.on('click', this.clickHandler);
    L.Marker.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    this.off('click', this.clickHandler);
    L.Marker.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
  },

  clickHandler: function (e) {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
      e.target.bindPopup(data.myProperty);
      e.target.openPopup();
    }, this);
  }

});

L.customMarker = function (latLng, options) {
  return new L.CustomMarker(latLng, options);
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hNlvhC?p=preview

This is ofcourse very crude, in a real implementation one would check in the `click` event if the popup is already binded so you don't bind it twice but it gives you a good idea of the possibilities of extending `L.Marker`

About storing the markers, you could just use a `L.LayerGroup` and a that to the map. When creating a marker you'de add it to the group. That way you could use the utility methods of the layergroup, like `hasLayer`, `getLayer`, `clearLayers`, `eachLayer` etc.

Here's the reference for `L.LayerGroup`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

Comment: Thank you so much, now i clearly see what can i achieve extending the marker class...